# Luatex + (shadows or fadings) tikzlibraries make "gotosource" from the first page jump to pgflibraryfadings.code.tex

Tags: luatex, forward-inverse-search, tikzlibrary

**Information about the problem**

The following code is ok with pdflatex and xelatex compilation.
But with Lualatex it produces the **problem** described below;

The problem occurs both with TexStudio and TexWorks editors. I didn't test other editors.

After some tests, it appears that the problem is conjunction of

- Lualatex
- synctex
- `\usetikzlibrary{fadings}` or `\usetikzlibrary{shadows}` (each of them separately or both used)

The problem occurs even without loading directly the two libraries, but loading some package using one of them as for exemple `\usepackage{worldflags}`.

**The problem is:** when right-click from the pdf to goto source (from the first page only), it jump to the pgflibraryfadings.code.tex (line 17). From the page 2 and followings all is as expected.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{article}
%\usepackage{lmodern} % for pdflatex    
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for pdflatex    
\usepackage{fontspec} % for xelatex or lualatex     
    \setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} 
    \setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans} 
    \setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono} 

\usepackage{tikz} 
    \usetikzlibrary{shadows} %or and the following
    \usetikzlibrary{fadings} % or and and the following
\usepackage{worldflags}

%---------------
\begin{document}
Page 1
Some text and math $0+1=1$

\newpage page 2
Some text and math $0+2=2$

\newpage page 3
Some text and math $0+3=3$

\end{document}
%---------------
```

Comment: When you load the `fadings` library, the standard fadings will be preloaded. Each fading is saved in a TeX box which triggers some typesetting function in TeX's core, including construction of SynTeX information. This might be a bug in LuaTeX that it writes SyncTeX information even for boxes that don't contain any characters.

Comment: @HenriMenke i opened an issue about this some time ago https://github.com/jlaurens/synctex/issues/44